# PHP syntax error, unexpected ' ; ' in web.php

Tags: laravel-5

When I want to run php artisan route:list, I found this in the log:

In web.php line 24:

syntax error, unexpected ';'

the code in web.php line 24 is:

Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

**I don't find any errors in your code.**

I know you are new in the community so welcome. You have to give details so we can help you.
Next time give full details of your error.